# How to delete Blanks in excel but with conditions

Tags: excel, vba

Is there any easy way with VBA to delete Blanks BUT NOT ALL

I'm usually using this code to delete blanks :

```
Option Explicit 

Sub DeleteBlanks() 
    Dim intCol As Integer 

    For intCol = 1 To 14 'cols A to D
        Range(Cells(2, intCol), Cells(146521, intCol)). _ 
        SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Delete Shift:=xlUp 
    Next intCol 
End Sub
```

But my situation is a little bit special and i cannot use this code
My table look like this one but with more columns :

```
Item     code     Description   Cond1      Cond2   ....
A        ID1      Alpha         1 BOX      10 BOX
B        
         ID1      Bravo         1 BOX      50 BOX
C        ID1      Charlie       1 BOX
D        
         ID1      Delta         5 BOX
E        ID1      Echo          2 BOX      20 BOX
F        ID1      Foxtrot       1 BOX      40 BOX
G        ID1      Golf          1 BOX      20 BOX
```

And i would like this :

```
 Item     code     Description   Cond1      Cond2   ....
A        ID1      Alpha         1 BOX      10 BOX
B        ID1      Bravo         1 BOX      50 BOX
C        ID1      Charlie       1 BOX
D        ID1      Delta         5 BOX
E        ID1      Echo          2 BOX      20 BOX
F        ID1      Foxtrot       1 BOX      40 BOX
G        ID1      Golf          1 BOX      20 BOX
```

The Goal is not to delete the blanks from columns COND2 etc but only to put the line in order when the ITEM and CODE is not on the same line.
I hope i was clear enough.
If it is possible to change easily the number of columns or line it would be great.
And also the same answer but with the the reorder from ITEM CODE and  DESCRIPTION.

If I'm not clear enough please ask me for more information.
Thanks in advance.
James

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you fill down the values in the first column you can then use some code to delete the blanks. 
the following code will fill in a selected range with values from above the blank

```
Sub Fill_in_blanks()
' this macro fills in blanks with the values above
' the empty cell
' it then does a copy paste special values to
' convert all the cells from a formula to a value
Dim myRng As Range

Set myRng = Selection


myRng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Select
Selection.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C"
myRng.Select
Selection.Copy
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
End Sub
```

you can then delete entire rows by selecting selecting column 2 and using this code to delete rows that have a blank column 2

```
Sub del_blank_zero()
Dim rng As Range
Dim mycell As Range
Set rng = Selection
For Each mycell In rng
    If mycell = 0 Or mycell = "" Then
        mycell.EntireRow.Delete
    End If
    'Debug.Print mycell.Address
Next mycell
End Sub
```

from your questions below I modified the delete code
Select the first column only and then run the code, it worked on the sample you provided
Not I used an offset of 10, if your data is wider or narrower you can just change that value

```
Sub del_blank_zero()
Dim rng As Range
Dim mycell As Range
Set rng = Selection
For Each mycell In rng
    If mycell.Offset(0, 1) = 0 Or mycell.Offset(0, 1) = "" Then
        Range(mycell.Offset(0, 1), mycell.Offset(0, 10)).Delete Shift:=xlUp
    End If
    If mycell = 0 Or mycell = "" Then
        mycell.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    End If
Next mycell
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It is solving one of my other problem on another project. But my problem is a little bit different.
Is it possible to make that like in my VBA code it delete the lines with blanks but only checking the blanks in the column A,B,C ?
So it would copy special past up not one columns after one but it would take all the columns next to C

Comment: Another point maybe i wasnt clear but the error in my table is not always the same. Sometimes I have multiple blanks line between each line

Comment: I have also blanks that are normal in columns COND2 and COND3 and so on. What I would like is a solution if it is possible to make the operation only checking the first colums and copy past and delete shift up the right ones. Let me know if it is not clear enough

Answer (score 0):

If sorted, I think you might just add a column (say A) with A2:

```
=IF(C1="",B1,B2)
```

copied down. Select ColumnA, Copy, Paste Special, Values over the top, move B1 to A1, delete ColumnB and filter to delete blanks in ColumnB.

Comment: Thanks for you answer but with the errors that I can found in my table, this solution doesn't work for my problem.